# How to use FontAwesome in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Newbie question. I did `meteor add fortawesome:fontawesome` which was successful. Then in my client folder I created style.css with

```
body {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

But its not having any effect.  Other default fonts such as `monospace`, `sans-serif` are working fine.

I dont mind downloading and adding css, fonts etc but to which folder should I copy them to?  `client` or `public`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAwesome is a font icon set library, it would make little sense to use it globally on the body.

You need to add markup to your templates to insert icons in your website using this syntax :

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

Have a look to FontAwesome docs to discover every icons and options available : http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 1):

Inside your template you have  to use i tags:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
```

For more information check the examples in the official page: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

you have a wide variety of icons to use: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/